# Stored procedure works in Crystal Reports but does not work in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a report that works fine with this stored procedure in Crystal Reports:

```
BEGIN "CMS"."CMS_RP_MERCHANDISE"."SP_M4_OH_ITEMS"(:MCUR, 1, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL); END ;
```

When I try to use the same stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer, I get this message:

> Error starting at line : 2 in command -
>   Error report -
>   ORA-06550: row 1 ، col 2543 :
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_M4_OH_ITEMS'
>   ORA-06550: row 1 ، col 2543 :
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

[This is stored procedure Declaration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Wo4DIUxdvDkMhj4OcRhY4HT2qKziGMC/view?usp=sharing)

[Image from sql dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfE5C.jpg)

Comment: please edit the question and show the complete pl/sql [mcve]

Comment: The call seems to be needlessly complicated. You don't need to set all those variables to null immediately after declaring them, as they are already null. If the procedure set defaults for parameters that are allowed to be null, you could use a much shorter call with less chance of errors. A wall of uppercase text is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

> wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_M4_OH_ITEMS'

I presume you did something wrong. That procedure has *zillion* of parameters, and it seems that you either missed some (i.e. you have too few or too many of them), or you missed their datatype (e.g. should be `NUMBER` but you provided a string).

Such a procedure is difficult to debug; error is in line 1, column 2543 (two thousand five hundred forty three?!); can't you format it somehow and make it easier to read and maintain? Who is going to scroll that far right?

Besides, you didn't post `CREATE PROCEDURE` code; we saw you declared many variables, passed them to the procedure, but - without seeing it, it is difficult to say much more. I hope you'll manage to fix it after reading what I wrote. Good luck!